# Call to Graph API in DLL fails when invoked from other application

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have written an application to make calls to the Microsoft Graph API using the sample code in the Quickstart. (Here in github:  https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2/tree/master/2-Call-OwnApi) I modified the code to make it a class library to read, add and delete events in Outlook calendars.  I added a simple forms based application to the solution to test the application.  Great success!

Next step was to modify an existing application to use this new DLL.  All of the Microsoft Graph settings (ClientId, ClientSecret and Tenant...) were brought over from testing the DLL.

When I run this code an attempt to retrieve a list of calendar events, the call to acquire the access token fails/crashes.  I don't get an exception, the code just exits.  Here are some pertinent snippets...

Call from VB.net code

```
Try
     eventArray = Await CalendarG.getCalendarEventsAsync(mailBoxEmail, DateTime.Today.AddMonths(6).AddDays(-7).ToString, DateTime.Today.AddMonths(7).AddDays(-7).ToString)
Catch ex As Exception
     Debug.Print(ex.Message)
End Try
```

C# DLL code

```
public async static Task<JArray> getCalendarEventsAsync(string calendarEmail, String startDate, String endDate)
{
    AuthenticationConfig config = AuthenticationConfig.ReadFromJsonFile("appsettings.json");
    IConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(config.ClientId)
            .WithClientSecret(config.ClientSecret)
            .WithAuthority(new Uri(config.Authority))
            .Build();

     string[] scopes = new string[] { $"{config.ApiUrl}.default" };

     string dtStart = DateTime.Parse(startDate).ToString("O");
     string dtEnd = DateTime.Parse(endDate).ToString("O");

     AuthenticationResult result = null;
     try
       {
           result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();                
       }
     catch (MsalServiceException ex) // when (ex.Message.Contains("AADSTS70011"))
       {
          throw new Exception($"Scope request rejected.  {ex.Message}");
       }
     catch (Exception ex1)  // not a MsalServiceException
       {
          throw new Exception($"Other token exception: {ex1.Message}");
       }
```

When stepping through the code, the code steps from the call into the CalendarG.getCalendarEventsAsync line, executes the code down to acquire the client token.  At that point it does not raise an exception but jumps back to the call in VB.net.  That line of code does not raise an exception either.  In fact the console says the calling app and previous threads all exited with code 0.  There is a ObjectDisposeException thrown to the Immediate Window at the very end that isn't caught.

Can anyone point me in an appropriate direction?  Why is the call for the client token not raising an exception?

Comment: Let me add the VB.Net code (see below) that i use at my end. Test it out and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are unfamiliar to async / await methods, you should definitely read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/async/#BKMK_HowtoWriteanAsyncMethod

And then you should probably read it again.

The pertinent line is:
*The method usually includes at least one await expression, which marks a point where the method can't continue until the awaited asynchronous operation is complete. In the meantime, the method is suspended, and **control returns to the method's caller**.*

So when execution gets to the first await statement, it returns to the caller, but it doesn't return the JArray.  The correct implementation would have a task handler ready to receive the JArray info when the async method finished.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the Vb.net code that i used.

```html
Public Partial Class MainWindow
    Inherits Window

    Private graphAPIEndpoint As String = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me"
    Private scopes As String() = New String() {"user.read"}

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Private Async Sub CallGraphButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs)
        Dim authResult As AuthenticationResult = Nothing
        Dim app = App.PublicClientApp
        ResultText.Text = String.Empty
        TokenInfoText.Text = String.Empty
        Dim accounts = Await app.GetAccountsAsync()
        Dim firstAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault()

        Try
            authResult = Await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, firstAccount).ExecuteAsync()
        Catch ex As MsalUiRequiredException
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"MsalUiRequiredException: {ex.Message}")

            Try
                authResult = Await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).WithAccount(accounts.FirstOrDefault()).WithPrompt(Prompt.SelectAccount).ExecuteAsync()
            Catch msalex As MsalException
                ResultText.Text = $"Error Acquiring Token:{System.Environment.NewLine}{msalex}"
            End Try

        Catch ex As Exception
            ResultText.Text = $"Error Acquiring Token Silently:{System.Environment.NewLine}{ex}"
            Return
        End Try

        If authResult IsNot Nothing Then
            ResultText.Text = Await GetHttpContentWithToken(graphAPIEndpoint, authResult.AccessToken)
            DisplayBasicTokenInfo(authResult)
            Me.SignOutButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```